# how to avoid replication of data in datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am developing `VB.Net` application, here i am using `DataGridView` control to display data from database now it is displaying as follows

```
emp no  emp name    city    Sal Description Salary  
54  john            NJ        HRA           1000    
54  john            NJ        DA            2500    
54  john            NJ        BP            12500
```

but i need to display as follows

```
emp no  emp name    city    Sal Description Salary  Net Sal
54      john         NJ       HRA           1000    
                              DA            2500    
                              BP            12500   16000
```

Since emp no,emp name and city is repeated i need not to display it again and net salary too should be displayed in the third row by adding HRA+DA+BP

Is there any possible to do this kindly advice on this

Comment: what is your datasource, is it DataSet or Collection or what?

Comment: Sorry for my late response i am using dataset to populate DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

use template feilds, in item template take datalist or grid for column salery discription and salery and use sql query to compute sum of salery for emp name in net salery

Answer (score 0):

what you want is something like `Master/Details` view so I think you have to split the result into two tables Inside your `DataSet`

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select distinct 
                                                       EmpNo,EmpName,City,
                                                       sum(salary) NetSalary 
                                                       from MyTable 
                                                       group by EmpNo,EmpName,City",
                                                       connection);
masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "Master");

SqlDataAdapter detailsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select distinct 
                                                       Empno,SalDescription,salary
                                                       from MyTable 
                                                       group by EmpNo,EmpName,City,SalDescription,salary",
                                                       connection);
detailsDataAdapter .Fill(data, "Details");
```

then create a relation between these two table as follows

```
DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("MasterDetails",
            data.Tables["Master"].Columns["EmpNo"],
            data.Tables["Details"].Columns["EmpNo"]);
data.Relations.Add(relation);
```

that means your form will contains two `DataGridViews` one for master and another for Details, you can show details rows according to selected row in master `DataGridView`